# Datetime currentTime issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code like this:

```
onPressed: isClick
                    ? () async {
                        isClick = false;
                        final DateTime dateCreated = DateTime.now();
                        setState(() {
                          dateCreated;
                        });
                        final userIp = await UserService.getIp();
                        final user = User(
                            name: _nameController.text,
                            surname: _surnameController.text,
                            email: _emailController.text,
                            year: _selectedValue,
                            dateCreated: DateFormat('dd/MM/y - HH:mm:ss').format(dateCreated),
                            ipAddress: userIp);
                        hasInternet = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
                        await UserService.insert([user.toJson()]);
                        if (hasInternet) {
                          showToast(StringConstants.registerOkayText, duration: 2, gravity: Toast.bottom);
                        } else {
                          showToast(StringConstants.registerNotOkayText, duration: 5, gravity: Toast.bottom);
                        }
                      }
                    : null,
```

The time is now 16.15 but the code prints the time as 13.14. How can I solve this? GMT?

Comment: Have you tried .toLocal()? Something like that DateFormat('dd/MM/y - HH:mm:ss').format(dateCreated).toLocal()

Comment: yes but not working toLocal().

Comment: @SonerB What timezone are your device set to (go into clock settings)? The definition of localtime in Dart are based on what your device are considering localtime. This issue are rather common if you do development in emulators since they are often not configured as you expect when it comes to timezone settings.

Comment: oh ım using emulator and ı am fix this.... thanks for helping :)

Comment: @julemand101 I fix this emulator time settings but not working... and ı use the personel phone like a emulator but not working to. :((((((((((((((((

Comment: @SonerB You are not showing the part where you show the time in your application. Can you show where you are using `dateCreated` and outputs it's value?

Comment: @julemand101 I found the problem. There is a problem with the "DateFormat" part in the 'intl' package I am using. When I used the plain Datetime data, it showed my local time. I also keep the data with google sheets. I keep the data with the User you see in the code section above and send it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the flutter package I use to edit the time format. My problem was fixed when I deleted the package and removed it from the code and ran it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want mobile time and want to format just use this plugin** [intl: ^0.17.0](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();

String s = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(date));
```

In the stirng s you will get the current date

**Or if you want to get the current internet time you just use**

[ntp: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp/install)

```
final int offset = await NTP.getNtpOffset(
          localTime: DateTime.now(), lookUpAddress: "time.google.com");
      DateTime internetTime =
          DateTime.now().add(Duration(milliseconds: offset));
```

here you will get the current time and date in `internetTime`

Comment: thanks but not working :(

Comment: can u tell me whats the exact issue

Comment: It didn't give an error, but it showed the same result. The clock showed 16:54 but 13:54.

Answer (score 0):

Your code of getting the date time looks good to me. It should give you the current local time of your computer. So obviously it can be due to the time settings of your computer. please check if that is configured to different timezone or may be if VPN check the timezone of vpn. Try this to see what is the timezone of your computer.
print(dateTime.timeZoneName);
print(dateTime.timeZoneOffset);

Comment: I did all the checks. But my local computer has no time issue and I don't use VPN either. I think the problem is in the 'DateFormat' that I use in the intl package. Because only when I use DateTime I can see the correct time.